# Count all classes in coffeescript project

Tags: bash, shell

I need to count all the classes in my project. The idea is pretty simple just count all the words class in the code.
I finished with the script below:

```
grep -r 'class' assets/coffee > wc -l
```

but for some reasons I see anything on my console

Comment: Whats that crazy `c` character you're using in `wc` ?

Comment: cyrillic:) sorry for that

Answer (score 2):

`>` redirects to a file called `wc`. `-l` is interpreted as an argument to `grep`, and happens to be a valid one so no error either.

I suppose you intended to use `grep | wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

You could even simplify your command line to `grep -rc 'class' assets/coffee`.
`grep -c` outputs the match count rather than the matches themselves.